# Сделал страницу в SceneBuilder для JavaFX. Страница перестала отвечать на нажатия (Перестали работать кнопки, радио кнопки и TextArea)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scene-builder

Компьютер создает рандомное число и пользователю нужно угадать его.
Вот fxml файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo.Application">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="512.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffcc99;">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="GuessedNubers" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="266.0" text="Guessed numbers: " textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="Between" layoutX="313.0" layoutY="255.0" opacity="0.74" text="Write number between 1/10!" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="BestResult" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="36.0" text="Best result: " textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="160.0" layoutY="14.0" text="&quot;Guess number game&quot;" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="31.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="315.0" layoutY="117.0" text="Try to guess my number (;" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </opaqueInsets>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="Answer_Text" layoutX="305.0" layoutY="182.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="182.0" promptText="My number is..." style="-fx-background-color: #666699;" text="1" />
            <Button fx:id="AnswerButton" layoutX="503.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="82.0" style="-fx-background-color: #009999;" text="Answer" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="GiveUpButton" layoutX="393.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="82.0" style="-fx-background-color: #009999;" text="Give Up" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="GenerateNewButton" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="163.0" style="-fx-background-color: #009999;" text="Generate new number" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Label fx:id="LastedAttempts" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="333.0" text="You have  attempts" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <RadioButton fx:id="VeryEasy" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="97.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="very easy" textFill="#666699">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Easy" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="130.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="easy" textFill="#666699">
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="5.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Normal" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="164.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="normal" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Hard" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="197.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="hard" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Harder" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="231.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="harder" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Insane" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="99.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="insane" textFill="#666699">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Freaks" layoutX="148.0" layoutY="132.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="for freaks" textFill="#666699">
               <padding>
                  <Insets right="5.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Gods" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="198.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="for gods" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Psychics" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="for psychics" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="Impossible" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="233.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="impossible for every one" textFill="#666699">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </RadioButton>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: А где класс приложения и контроллер? Сам по себе fxml файл работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

В норме все поведение программы определяется ее кодом, написанным на Java. FXML файлы, как правило, определяют только внешний вид окна, но не его поведение. Для того, чтобы программа могла как-то реагировать на действия пользователя, с элементами интерфейса (кнопки, элементы ввода и т.п.) нужно связать т. наз. "слушатели", или, иначе говоря, обработчики для всех видов событий, которые должны обрабатываться (нажатие, получения фокуса ввода и т. п.). "Слушатель" (listener) -- это фрагмент программного кода, который будет выполняться, когда произойдет событие. В простейшем случае это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
    myButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Нажата кнопка " 
                              + ((Button)(e.getSource())).getText()));
```

Здесь с кнопкой `myButton` связывается слушатель для события типа `ActionEvent`, которое будет сгенерировано кнопкой при нажатии. В этом фрагменте из обекта, содержащего информацию о событии и представленого в коде параметром `e`, извлекается элемент интерфейса, вызвавшего событие (`e.getSource()`) (в данном случае это будет сама эа кнопка) и на консоль выводится ее текст.

В некоторых случаях можно добавлять обработчики событий прямо в FXML файле (см. напр. [вот это описание](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/fxml.html), параграф **FXML Event Handlers**), но такая практика, я бы сказал, на любителя.

Comment: У меня есть класс контроллер. Также другие страницы, которые вполне работают.

Comment: Также у меня есть обработчики событий, на кнопках: обычных и радио.

Comment: @Someone ну вот там и ищите причину. Проверьте назначение обработчиков кнопкам, вставьте в обработчики отладочный вывод и убедитесь, что они вызываются, еще что-то. FXML на обработку событий никак не влияет, если только вы не приделывали обработчиков в нём, причина не в нём.

Comment: @Someone Может быть, вы забыли связать элементы интерфейса в коде с элементами, описанными в FXML? Это делается аннотацией `@FXML`, напр. `@FXML private TextField myTextFieldField;` . Имена в коде и в FXML должны совпадать., т.е. в FXML должно стоять `<TextField fx:id="myTextFieldField" .... />`  в этом случае.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Проверю всё.